# configure npm&webpack Win10 for long paths using relative paths

Tags: npm, webpack, config, long-path

Current **webpack bundling project folder structure (win10)**:
root_folder\ 
|--node_modules
|--src
   |--index.js
   |--template.html
|--package.json
|--webpack.config.js

Contents of **index.js**:
`console.log("Hello webpack");`

Contents of **template.html**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Contents of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Contents of webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/template.html'), // template file
            filename: 'index.html', // output file
        }),
    ]
};
```

How to make this folder completely portable, i.e. when running `npx webpack` or `npm run build` this always can run well, no matter if working with `C:\root_folder\` or with `C:\very\longpath\root_folder`.

Have successfully ran `npx webpack` for this example in `C:\root_folder\` and then i copied ** root_folder ** like it is into `D:\testing\root_folder\` and when running `npx webpack` from `D:\testing\root_folder\` it worked, which obviously shows it is portable.

Summary: It is helpful to store root folders of webpack bundling projects if they belong to other projects in their own project subfolder, so it is useful to be able to have root_folder sometimes in nested folders.

Question: Is there available a way to resolve all root_folder/ scripts with local paths in windows with simple npm scripts or even npx command, so it will not return error for long paths? 

Current Answer: Well found which works is copying the nested root_folder to a temporary `C:\temp\root_folder` and from there do all the npm webpack processing and also module bundling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer which worked here was to mount the project directory and from there run the build.

All of what is necessary is to have the following npm scripts (in package.json):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "ECHO \"Error: no test specified\" && EXIT 1",
    "build": "(IF EXIST \"%CD%/dist\" RMDIR dist /S /Q) && webpack",
    "nestingcompliance:build": "SUBST Z: \"%CD%\" && PUSHD Z: && npm run build && POPD && SUBST Z: /D"
  }
```

And then run in cmd line:

```
npm run nestingcompliance:build
```